# Antenna matching circuit - weird behaviour

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance-matching, vna

I have a 2.4GHz device with room for a Pi matching circuit. I cut J5 (to disconnect the MCU - brown line in layout picture), soldered the ground of the coaxial cable in the white region and the feedline from the coax going to the VNA where it's marked in light green.
[image]
[image]

Calibrated the VNA using C24 to install a short and the 50R as load calibration. With that done, I soldered 100pF caps as shorts in L1 and C23 and started measuring  to get a baseline. With the help of a series capacitor (0.5pF) and a shunt inductor (6.8nH) I went from the green trace in the Smith chart to the red one and from a VSWR of of ~7 to 1.17. In theory the gains should've been massive. However, and this is what I'm puzzled about, doing back to back tests (transmission) with a device that only has the 100pF caps in series, the wireless performance is nearly identical.

[image]

I racked my brain over this and can't find any decent explanation. The only theory (and it's a pretty weak one) is that angling the feedline of the coax back towards the MCU somehow influenced my readings. I've used the same VNA and tools to match another device a few weeks back and it all worked perfectly, so I'm quite puzzled.